# flex/bison not terminating on <<EOF>>

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have a simple project using flex/bison. I'm trying to parse a text file, but it doesn't quits parsing (apparently a loop at end of file).

My flex code:

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
%%
[0-9]                           { printf("digit: %s\n",yytext); return DIGIT; }
[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚçÇãõÃÕ]+       { printf("word: %s\n",yytext); return WORD; }

[\.]                            
[ ]        
[\n]             

.                               { printf("other: %s\n",yytext); return OTHER; }

<<EOF>>                         { yyterminate(); return 0; }
%%
```

My bison code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

%token DIGIT WORD OTHER SPACE

%%
start :
    text
    ;

text :
    | WORD text
    ;

%%

extern FILE *yyin;

main()
{
    printf("Translating...\n");
    printf("\n");

    if ((yyin = fopen("/home/nilo/text","r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"File not found or not readable.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Start the parser
    yyparse();

    fprintf(stderr,"Parser ended...\n");
}

yyerror(s)
char *s;
{
    printf("yacc error: %s\n", s);
}

yywrap()
{
    return(0);
}
```

I've already tried not to put `<<EOF>>` rule and some other things related to this, like calling yyterminate(), calling return 0, both things, etc., but no success.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, got it working...

When I initially started to play with this code, I did it using the famous "ctrl-c/ctrl-v" feature... :)

When "yywrap()" return 0, this indicates that the EOF had been reached but the parsing must continue. This is particularly true on interactive parsers.

Getting input from a file, as it's the present situation, we have 3 alternatives to quit the parsing on end-of-file situation:

1. Put an %option noyywrap on lex specifications and remove the yywrap() code on your side OR
2. Change your yywrap() to returns 1 to quit parsing OR
3. Change your yywrap() to set yyin to another file and returns 0 to continues parsing the newly added file.